# why when a file is upload using post presigned url the returned response doesnot have the key

Tags: amazon-s3, post, status, pre-signed-url

I am currently using post presigned url to upload photos to my bucket, however when the upload is complete the response status is 204 and this response doesnot contain the key. Is it possible to return the key when the file is uploaded using post presigned url

Answer (score 0):

In case that `createPresignedPost` creation succeeds, its response is 204, it does not return the key as a response's field.
Check out this code which helps you achieve that.

server side:

```
const presignedKey = 'your/key'

var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Fields: {
    key: presignedKey
  }
};

s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Presigning post data encountered an error', err);
  } else {
    data.Fields.key = presignedKey;
    console.log('The post data is', data);
  }
});
```

The client-side should iterate over the response value which already contains the `key` field.

```
const formData = new FormData()

Object.keys(presignedUrlResponse?.fields).forEach(key => {
    formData.append(key, presignedUrlResponse?.fields[key])
})

formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(file))
```

Comment: Thats not my problem i cant get key from presigned url thats easy. What I am refering too when the file is uploaded using presigned url the response of the upload process doesnot have the key

Comment: ok, I got you, if you need that for tracking the upload, cant you use a simple solution like saving it in a map? @Ahmed